# When comparing revisions in SVN I get Access to the path is denied

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

When I am viewing a commit list in tortoise svn and double click to review changes, for some files I get the following message

Access to the Path c:\users\\AppData\Local\Temp\filenmae-revbase is denied.

If its any help I am using code compare to view differences, it does however still happen if using tortoise diff with a different message of access denied.

Could any one shed any light on why this happens.

The folder does exist and I am logged in as user with username

Thanks

Ben

Answer (score 0):

Check the permissions to your %TEMP% directory. You don't have enough permissions to access your %TEMP%, but normally you should have Full Access.

Comment: I do have full control all the way down from c:\users\username

Answer (score 0):

Further to this, it was caused by McAffee, when comparing javascript files it attempts to load the file to be compared from source control into the temp folder.

There is a McAffee rule which stops the execution or reading of javascript from the temp directory.